# Json : generate object id instead of real object

Tags: json, jackson

On my server I have complex objects but in my web client I would like to get a simple representation of these objects.
I would like to replace object with their id for example:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Event{
    private Long id;
private String name;
    private User user;

    @JsonProperty("event_id")
public Long getId() {
     return event_id;
    }
    public String getName() {
     return name;
    }
    public String getUser() {
     return user;
    }
    ....setters
}
```

When generating Json I will get Event class and user class inside
Is there anyway to replace the User with user id?
Since I have many complex objects I am looking for an elegant way like maybe an annotation over the User object that will return only the object id.

Ofcourse I will need the other way around. getting the id and transforming it to the object.

BTW: I'm using Jackson

Any Ideas?

10x
Noam

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a property for Id and ignore the sub-entity property like this:

```
class Event {
    private User user;

    public Long getUserId() {
        return user.getId();
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.user = retrieveUserById(userId); // or any other code         
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea how to achieve it. You can use `@JsonRawValue(true)` annotation on your `user` property. This will make Jackson treat `user` object as already serialized stuff. And then just override `.toString()` method for `User` class to make it return it's id as a string.

So in your `Event` class:

```
public class Event {
    ...
    @JsonRawValue(true)
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

And in your `User` class:

```
public class User {
    ...
    private Integer id;
    ...
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id.toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

This will result in e.g. `"user": 5` in your json (no double quotes will be added around `User` object serizlized value).